# RegEx for number greater than 1120

Tags: regular-expression

I know there are plenty of examples of this but I cannot seem to get this working. Could you guys please help me create a regex that will match any number greater than 1120?

Comment: How much greater? Matching integers between 1121 and 9999 is different from matching integers with more digits. It's also quite different if `1120` is a hexadecimal, decimal or octal number.

Comment: There are different types of regex, `BRE` , `ERE` , `PCRE` and more.... your question is to vague...

Comment: I'm sorry, I just needed a way to check the license count for our VPN devices. They have a limit of 1125 and our load-balancers need to monitor this and not send traffic to them if they are beyond this value. Surely, if its marked as down, they will not receive more so logically, the number shouldnt increase after 1120 but I just want to be sure by stating "greater than 1120".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RegEx is not a good method to solve this problem. Having said that, something
like this might work:

```
112[1-9]|11[3-9][0-9]|1[2-9][0-9][0-9]|[2-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]
```

Comment: Yeah, I know. Somehow you always end up with other numbers matching etc. Like the other comments, I don't really have a set limit. But it's for VPN devices that has a set limit of 1125 licenses. I want to mark the devices as down when they reach 1120 so they won't accept new connections. So the number should not increase after 1120 but just to be sure I want a range of numbers after 1120. This one should work perfectly. :)